# stream a video file from nodejs server to many HTML5 clients simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, video, npm

I have search in the web how to stream a video.mp4 to many html5 clients simultaneously at the same time. 
I read some tutorials but I don't see the right thing in nodejs to do this yet.

Have you some ways to explore?

Comment: do you want to stream or just serve a static video file?

Comment: Static file. The broadcasting with a static video file

Comment: then just serving the file using express (syntax in the answer below) should solve your problem

Comment: Thank's. But If I we want to stream a video file like live broadcasting, This code is not the good one. I want to broadcast file without possibility to control the video. Something like this socket.broadcast.emit('my_video',chunck) .But I know socket.io is not the right way. I learn somethinc like fs.createReadStream but it doesn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use express to serve videos as stain files - this will allow multiple HTML5 clients stream your video.

The syntax is very simple - you put the videos into a given folder and tell express to serve static files from that folder.

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

//Tell express which folder to use to server static files (can be more than one)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'video_folder')));

//Listen for requests
app.listen(3000);
```

Having said this, if you need a good user experience you probably want to use a dedicated streaming server, and may need to provide several different versions of your video to cater for different devices. You will also need to have different bit rate versions of the video to allow for different network conditions if using an adaptive bit rate protocol (the client requests the video chunk by chunk and selects the bit rate for each chunk depending on the network conditions).

Take a look at some of the open source Streaming servers to get a feel for whether you need to use one - e.g. GStreamer: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org

Comment: Thank's. But If I we want to stream a video file like live broadcasting, this code is not the good one. I want to broadcast file without possibility to control the video. Something like this socket.broadcast.emit('my_video',chunck) .But I know socket.io is not the right way. I learn somethinc like fs.createReadStream but it doesn't resolve my problem